# Is it possible to bulk load textfile into Table instead for External Table in Netezza?

Tags: netezza

I am bulk loading data in to Netezza from the text file using EXTERNAL TABLE and after loading data in to external table I am updating those some columns in the same external table since you cannot update external table I have to stage all the data from external table to one Temp Table and than I able able to do the updates whereas Is there any other way where I can directly bulk load the textfile data into the Table instead of External Table in Netezza?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using straight ODBC.  I would consider a "Transient External Table"

`INSERT INTO target_table SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL 'C:\FileName.txt'
using( delim '|' datestyle 'MDY' datedelim '/' REMOTESOURCE 'ODBC' MAXERRORS 50
LOGDIR 'C:\');`

Comment: not sure why this was downvoted, however, this worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at `nzload` http://www.enzeecommunity.com/message/12759

Example:
To load the database dev as user admin with the password production, specifying the table name areacode, using tab delimiters, and specifying the input file as phone-prefix.
dat, enter:

nzload -u admin -pw production -db dev -t areacode -delim '\t' -df
phone-prefix.dat

Answer (score 0):

Try nzload, as @cairnz said. Also, If you are connecting over ODBC, you can use the `REMOTESOURCE ODBC` option to load from a text file into a table, bypassing the creation of a separate external table. Take a look at the Netezza Data Loading Guide PDF provided by IBM.